# call to a member function rowcount() on null de PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al momento de registrar un usuario por medio de un formulario, cuando le doy guardar me aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_mvc\controladores\administradorControlador.php on
>   line 55

La línea 55 es la de la condición del `if`.

Acá dejo la porción de código en la que me aparece el error.

Este es mi controlador:

```
$consulta1=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT AdminDNI FROM admin WHERE AdminDNI='$dni'");  

       if ($consulta1->rowCount()>=1) {
          # code...
          $alerta=[

            "Alerta"=>"simple",
            "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado!",
            "Texto"=>"El DNI ingresado ya se encuentra registrado en el sistema. Por favor intente nuevamente.",
            "Tipo"=>"error"
          ];
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
protected function agregar_administrador_modelo($datos){

        $sql=mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO admin(AdminDNI,AdminNombre,AdminApellido,AdminTelefono,AdminDireccion,CuentaCodigo) 
       VALUES(:DNI,:Nombre,:Apellido,:Telefono,:Direccion,:Codigo)");//Marcadores
        $sql->bindParam(":DNI",$datos['DNI']);
        $sql->bindParam(":Nombre",$datos['Nombre']);
        $sql->bindParam(":Apellido",$datos['Apellido']);
        $sql->bindParam(":Telefono",$datos['Telefono']);
        $sql->bindParam(":Direccion",$datos['Direccion']);
        $sql->bindParam(":Codigo",$datos['Codigo']);

        $sql->execute();

        return $sql;        
    }
```

Esto comprueba si existe una fila en la BD y lanza la alerta. ¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser?

Comment: Verifica que la variable $dni realmente se le está pasando algún valor.

Comment: creo que si, por que si por que me añade algunos registros en la bd con el dni. Igualmente lo voy a verificar de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: El problema me lo causa, la funcion rowCount() por que si la elimino de mi codigo, me registra los usuarios correctamente, el problema es que al quitar esta funcion no puedo comprobar si ya existen o no usuarios repetidos, alguen conoce una funcion que haga lo mismo que rowCount()?

Comment: Puedes colocar por favor todo el código que involucra a la variable `$consulta1`

Comment: ahi agregué el modelo

Comment: Hay una confusión porque muestras dos métodos diferentes, por favor debes publicas el código del método mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple() que muestras en tu pregunta, o es un desliz?